# Changing background color of WebView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've seen this asked many times, but no clear answers. Additionally, all the answers were pre-JavaFX 8 and there must be a solution by now. I need the background color to the transparent.

Comment: Answers should be in answers. I have edited your solution into its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hava a look at this JIRA issue.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8116513
At the end of the comments is a description of a hack that might be helpful for you, and don't forget to vote for
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090547
to get this finally fixed.

Comment: Could you post the relevant piece of code, just in case the link dies?

Comment: Thanks! I voted, and I'm going to attempt that code now.

Comment: @mipa I don't understand why I need to hack in a solution if it says the issue is resolved on the webpage you linked. It says there is an official solution in 1.8. Where is the official solution?

Comment: RT-29186 is a prerequisite for RT-25004 as far as I understand it. So the full solution has not yet been implemented. I also don't know whether this has already made it into the current release. So, just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was from thanks to [Harry Hurr](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8116513).

I had to change like two small things in order to get it to work. If yours still isn't working, you probably imported the wrong things.

```
//put this line before you loadContent
webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(new WebDocumentListener(webEngine));

class WebDocumentListener implements ChangeListener<Document> { 
    private final WebEngine webEngine; 

    public WebDocumentListener(WebEngine webEngine) { 
        this.webEngine = webEngine; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> arg0, 
            Document arg1, Document arg2) { 
        try { 
            // Use reflection to retrieve the WebEngine's private 'page' field. 
            Field f = webEngine.getClass().getDeclaredField("page"); 
            f.setAccessible(true); 
            WebPage page = (WebPage) f.get(webEngine); 
            // Set the background color of the page to be transparent. 
            page.setBackgroundColor((new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)).getRGB()); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        } 
    } 
}
```